# Jetbrains как настроить sass компилятор?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains

Доброе утро!

Хочу настроить препроцессор в Idea Ide через Node js.

Я установил Node js и node-sass.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В самой ide такие настройки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоле:

```
9:25:22 An exception occurred while executing watcher 'Sass'. Watcher has been disabled. Fix it.: Cannot run program "C:\Users\mk\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass" (in directory "C:\Users\mk\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\SFAK-popup"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32
9:25:53 An exception occurred while executing watcher 'Sass'. Watcher has been disabled. Fix it.: Cannot run program "C:\Users\mk\node_modules\.bin\node-sass" (in directory "C:\Users\mk\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\SFAK-popup"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32
```

Пробовал поставлять разные файлы, например node-sass(\node_modules\node-sass\bin)

Подскажите, что не так и как исправить?

Comment: Idea, но там суть как я понимаю одна

Comment: Могу предположить что проблема в аргументах, с котороыми запускается ехешник

Comment: там же не exe, там просто node-sass. Удалил все аргументы - аналогично.  Насколько я понимаю, ошибка вот: CreateProcess error=193, %1 не является приложением Win32

Comment: что такое ноде-сасс?

Comment: как я понял это и есть sass в node )

Comment: @VINET у тебя должен сначала запуститься node.js а как его программа запуститься уже node-sass. В `node_sass.cmd` проверяй доступны ли все команды, виден ли `node` когда он вызывается и т.д. Была такая ошибка, там просто не правильно стартавал нод, а приложение пыталось запустить `.js` как отдельную программу. Удали все аргументы, добейся запуска именно интерпритатора, и самого скрипта